# Enchant particle 1.16.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-optifine

I've been trying to figure out how to make particles falling from the ceiling in 1.16.1 (I have optifine and it's java) but all my tries just failed , not a single particle appear, of course I checked if seeing particles was on and it is! Can someone help me please ? So I wanna make particle going from the ceiling to the floor , I tried with enchant particles and witch as well.
Hope someone have a solution !

Comment: you used the /particle command? whats the one you tried

Comment: Video about the `particle` command in 1.16: https://youtu.be/zITkUrNbQt4